# Prevent certain referrers from using my oAuth API

Tags: google-oauth

According to my Google API console my top referrer is https://www.googleapis.com which I assume is normal, but it's followed closely by http://blocvox.com which I don't know what they are and I am suspicious as to why they are consuming a lot of my requests and jeopardizing my capped usage.

How can I prevent this referrer from accessing my API?

Note: I am not using an API Key (which does support the blocking of referrers) I am using the oAuth method.

Comment: which api are you using?

Comment: I'm using the Google Calendar API v3 via my Chrome extension, it uses javascript.

Comment: @Jason I just stumbled across this. I'm the creator of Blocvox (currently on my back burner). For a while I was experimenting with every random way to drive traffic to it and, after noticing how some marketers used the referrer to advertise to site owners indirectly through Google Analytics reports, I temporarily hardcoded my browser referer to the URL you saw. I'm surprised it interfered with your extensions - apologies for any inconvenience. I love your extensions, btw.

Answer (score 0):

The details depend on what your API is written in, but most popular Web frameworks allow you to look at the referrer value for the HTTP request.  You could go further; most Web front-end servers allow you to filter/discard/reject/redirect queries based on the referrer field.

Comment: I'm using a Chrome extension to access the Google API, so it's written in javascript. So my extension's referrer would be my users's local machine? Since the extension is installed on any user's machine. I'm still confused as to what is causing the referrer to point to blocvox. Would you have an example of how I could micmic this or filter this?